# Menhir: --external-tokens can't seem to find Tokens module

Tags: ocaml, menhir

I have a `tokens.ml` file which has a `type token` statement in it. I also have a `tokens.mli` with the same `type token` statement. Now, I have a `parser.mly` which uses the tokens from `tokens.mly`. I want to keep my tokens in `tokens.ml/mli` and my parser in `parser.mly`.

So, I tried compiling my parser using the command

```
menhir parser.mly --table --explain --external-tokens Tokens
```

This gives me an error saying one of my tokens does not exist. Specifically,

```
File "parser.mly", line 173, characters 4-12:
Error: OPERATOR is undefined.
```

So, menhir is not finding the `Tokens` module. I don't know how to make it visible to `menhir`. I tried making a `tokens.cma` library, but even then I still get the same error.

Menhir doesn't seem to care if the module doesn't exist, because if I run the command

```
menhir parser.mly --table --explain --external-tokens SomeNonExistentModule
```

It still gives the same error about `OPERATOR` being undefined.

How do I get Menhir to find my tokens module. I would prefer to not use ocamlbuild. If you suggest an ocamlbuild solution, please at least explain the intermediate manual steps I could do instead. I want to understand what Menhir expects.

Comment: In your parser.mly file, do you still have the %token OPERATOR directive at the top?

Comment: Do I need to have that? I definitely do not have that

Comment: I believe so... My understanding is that the --external-tokens directive exists only so that the generated parser.ml and .mli files will not have the token type defined, and instead will reference the external token module.  You still need %token ... inside the .mly file

Comment: You need it anyway for specifying priority/associativity, and also the [docs](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/manual.html#sec3) allude to autogenerating the tokens.ml file from the grammar specification, so it's assumed that the %token directives are there

Comment: Yes but the docs also say the tokens file can be written by hand and not autogenerated. I'll try that though, thank you.

Comment: Yep that did it. Feel free to write an answer and I'll accept. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the error arises because you do not have the

```ml
%token OPERATOR
```

declaration in your `.mly` file.

Menhir's `--external-tokens T` option exists to have the generated parser module use `T.token` instead of generating the token type from the declarations, however the declarations are still necessary inside the `.mly` file.

As a side note, you can have your tokens in a separate `.mly` file (e.g. `tokens.mly`), which will look like below:

tokens.mly:

```ml
%token <int> INT
%token EOF
%%
```

parser.mly:

```ml
%start <int> f
%%

f : n = INT; EOF { n }
```

and then you can run the following commands:

```
menhir tokens.mly --only-tokens
menhir parser.mly tokens.mly --external-tokens Tokens --base parser
```

which can be useful if you want to reuse the tokens across parsers etc.

(you can also skip the `--only-tokens` bit and write tokens.ml by hand, to be consistent with tokens.mly)